# Is there a way to write successive for loops in one line in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

For example, I would like to create a set with n 0s and m 1s, `[0, 0, ...0, 1, 1, ..., 1]`. Is there a way to do something like `[0 for i in range(n), 1 for j in range(m)]`?

Comment: From the comments to answers it looks like what you're really trying to do is something else. Can you give context and explain your real goal?

Answer (score 4):

You can create the two lists separately, then add them like this:

```
[0 for i in range(n)] + [1 for j in range(m)]
```

Or simply use list multiplication:

```
[0]*n + [1]*m
```

Comment: Ok, I suppose there is no way to put two successive for loops in one line? My example was bad.

Comment: @fishman11235 You can put two for loops in one line, but not separate them with a comma, for instance, you can do `[x + y for x in range(n) for y in range(m)]` (which is different from what you want to do).

Comment: This is however doing a very different thing (looping n*m times, not n+m)

Comment: @mozway I know, it was just to show that you can put two (or more) for loops in one line, not necessarily to solve OPs problem.

Comment: Strictly speak, none of these are putting two for-loops on one line, that isnt' possible, for-loops are compound statements, you can't put mutiple for-loops on a single line.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sure, I was considering the literal meaning of line, since you can put as many for loops as your memory could handle on a single line.

Comment: @MrGeek no, *you can't*. You can put at most 1 for-loop on a single line. There are no for-loops in your code. You have two *list comprehensions*, which aren't for loops. They are another type of language construct, an expression. Whereas for-loops are compound statements. And that may sound pedantic, but this is *programming* after all.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You are correct, I understand and I hope the OP does too that they aren't _for loop_ statements, I'm calling them for loops just to simplify it, given they share some similarities with for statements.

Answer (score 2):

In the event you wanted to do this without having to add two lists together (e.g. if `n` and `m` are very large and you want to be able to generate this sequence without putting it all into a list), you could iterate over the combined range with a conditional:

```
>>> n, m = 2, 3
>>> [0 if i < n else 1 for i in range(n + m)]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

You can also use `itertools.chain` to "add" two generators together:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain((0 for _ in range(n)), (1 for _ in range(m))))
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was about to suggest ;) +1

Answer (score 2):

Stop thinking in terms of doing things in a single line. Think in terms of using *useful, modular, extensible abstractions*. For these sorts of things, `itertools` provides a lot of useful abstractions.

```
>>> from itertools import repeat, chain
>>> list(chain(repeat(0, 4), repeat(1, 3)))
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Start building your own useful abstractions by combining smaller useful abstractions:

```
>>> from itertools import repeat, chain, starmap
>>> def builder(*pairs, consume=list):
...     return consume(chain.from_iterable(starmap(repeat, pairs)))
...
>>> builder((0,3), (1, 4), (2,1), (3, 6))
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Although, sometimes, simpler is better, and learn to take advantage of the various syntactic sugars provided by the language:

```
>>> [*repeat(0, 4), *repeat(1, 3), *repeat(2,2)]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Option with `chain()` with `repeat()` should be really efficient for long sequences.

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```
lst = [0]*n+[1]*m
```

Comment: This produces a tuple with two lists.

Comment: it should work now

Answer (score 0):

Yet another potential solution for your problem using list comprehension and 2 for loops

```py
n,m = 3,4
[i for i,n_numbers in enumerate((n,m)) for _ in range(n_numbers) ]
```